# apply function on groups of k elements of a pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, mean, series

I have a pandas Series:

```
0     1
1     5
2    20
3    -1
```

Lets say I want to apply `mean()` on every two elements, so I get something like this:

```
0    3.0
1    9.5
```

Is there an elegant way to do this?

Comment: I've updated my post.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.groupby.html) by `index` divide by `k=2`:

```
k = 2
print (s.index // k)
Int64Index([0, 0, 1, 1], dtype='int64')

print (s.groupby([s.index // k]).mean())
   name
0   3.0
1   9.5
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way to deal with the case that k does not divide the length of the series? I tried: (s[-m:].index // k) when k divides m, but it did not work

Comment: I think I catch it. But you need first `reset_index` - `s = s[-m:].reset_index(drop=True)` and then use `print (s.groupby([s.index // k]).mean())`

Comment: Got it, so I guess need to do [(s.index + ((k - (len(s) % k)) % k)) // k]

Answer (score 1):

If you are using this over large series and many times, you'll want to consider a fast approach.  This solution uses all numpy functions and will be fast.

Use `reshape` and construct new `pd.Series`

consider the `pd.Series` `s`

```
s = pd.Series([1, 5, 20, -1])
```

---

***generalized function***

```
def mean_k(s, k):
    pad = (k - s.shape[0] % k) % k
    nan = np.repeat(np.nan, pad)
    val = np.concatenate([s.values, nan])
    return pd.Series(np.nanmean(val.reshape(-1, k), axis=1))
```

***demonstration***

```
mean_k(s, 2)

0    3.0
1    9.5
dtype: float64
```

---

```
mean_k(s, 3)

0    8.666667
1   -1.000000
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
(s.iloc[::2].values + s.iloc[1::2])/2
```

if you want you can also reset the index afterwards, so you have 0, 1 as the index, using:

```
((s.iloc[::2].values + s.iloc[1::2])/2).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: My bad, was a bit too quick ;)

Comment: This works good for the k=2 case, but I want to do this for many k's...

Comment: Mmmm should still be possible though, I'll think about it a bit :).